# Cómo puedo leer el valor "i:type" de un nodo xml?

Tags: .net, xml, vb, type

Tengo una duda: 
Tengo el siguiente XML el cual tiene un nodo llamado "FormaDePago". Este tiene una propiedad llamada i:type. Esta propiedad puede tener 4 valores posibles (FormaDePagoEnEfectivoOutput, FormaDePagoConvenioOutput, FormaDePagoDebitoTarjetaOutput y FormaDePagoDebitoBancarioOutput). Mi duda es como puedo leer ese valor para luego hacer un select case del mismo?
Les dejo la instrucción que uso para leer los nodos y el XML.

Muchas gracias!

Instrucción:

```html
nodo.SelectSingleNode("nameSpace1:Polizas/nameSpace1:PolizaOutput/nameSpace1:FormaDePago", nsmgr)
```

XML:

```js
<Body xmlns:d2p1="Service.Core.CarteraManager.DataContracts.Output">
        <d2p1:LoteOutput>
            <d2p1:EstadoDescarga>2</d2p1:EstadoDescarga>
            <d2p1:NumeroLote>42531</d2p1:NumeroLote>
            <d2p1:Polizas>
                <d2p1:PolizaOutput>
                    <d2p1:FormaDePago i:type="d2p1:FormaDePagoEnEfectivoOutput">
                        <d2p1:Cuotas>0</d2p1:Cuotas>
                        <d2p1:PrimerCuotaPaga>false</d2p1:PrimerCuotaPaga>
                        <d2p1:Calle>ARMENIA</d2p1:Calle>
                        <d2p1:CodigoLocalidad>2632</d2p1:CodigoLocalidad>
                        <d2p1:CodigoPostal>1822</d2p1:CodigoPostal>
                        <d2p1:CodigoProvincia>2</d2p1:CodigoProvincia>
                        <d2p1:Departamento i:nil="true" />
                        <d2p1:Numero>1133</d2p1:Numero>
                        <d2p1:Oficina i:nil="true" />
                        <d2p1:Piso>0</d2p1:Piso>
                    </d2p1:FormaDePago>
            </d2p1:Polizas>
         </d2p1:PolizaOutput>
      <d2p1:LoteOutput>
```